# Strong Mathematical Induction

Tags: proof-writing

$
a_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 2 & n=1 \\
 6 & n=2 \\
 a_{n-1}+9a_{n-2} & n\geq 3 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$\forall n \in N^+$, $a_n < 3^n$.

So far, I have assumed that $a_{n-1} \le (n-1)$ then, $(n-1) + 9(n-2) < 3^n$, then $10n-19 < 3^n$. Does this cover all cases where $n>3$?

Would this be a correct step to take? can anybody verify?

Comment: Oh... how would you approach this question? @fleablood

Comment: "So far, I have assumed that $a_{n−1}≤(n−1)$"  Why on earth would you assume that? $a_1 > 1-1; a_2 > 2-1; a_3 > 3-1$.  So far as I can tell that is *never* true.  So it covers *none* of the cases.

Comment: I would assume $a_{k} < 3^k$ for all $k \le n$ and show therefore that $a_{n+1} < 3^{n+1}$.

Comment: For $n\ge 5$ the statement is false:
$$
\begin{array}{l|l|l}
n & a_n & 3^n\\
\hline
 1 & 2. & 3 \\
 2 & 6. & 9 \\
 3 & 24. & 27 \\
 4 & 78. & 81 \\
 5 & 294. & 243 \\
 6 & 996. & 729 \\
 7 & 3642. & 2187 \\
 8 & 12606. & 6561 \\
 9 & 45384. & 19683 \\
 10 & 158838. & 59049 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: $a_{n+1} = a_n + 9a_{n-1} < 3^n + 9*3^{n-1} = 3^n + 3^{n+1}$ Hmmm... And as Raffaele points out $a_5 > 3^5$

Comment: You can prove  $a_n > 3^n; n \ge 5$ by induction.  $a_{n+1} = a_n + 9a_{n-1} > 3^n + 9*3^{n-1} = 3^n + 3^{n+1} > 3^{n+1}$ so only requires verifying that $a_5 > 3^5$ and $a_6 > 3^6$.

Comment: @Raffaele and fleablood sorry, but if n = 10, shouldn't it be subbed into $a_{n-1}$ and $9a_{n-2}$ which equals to $a_9$ and $9a_8%$ which equals 
 $9 + 72?$

Comment: @user498021 Maybe it is not clear enough to you how these recurrences work. Try to make a table by hand, just the first five/six rows and you'll soon realize the meaning of recursion

Comment: Ah, ok. I just did it and I see how i'm supposed to use the previous $a_n$ to find the current one. But I have a question. If $a_1$ and $a_2$ were not given this sequence we wouldn't know the recurrence right?

Comment: @fleablood, regarding your comment of induction, 3n+9∗3n−1, How did you arrive at this step? understand all the steps up to there, then i'm lost

Comment: @fleablood pls help :(

Comment: I need your help fleablood. thank you.

Comment: How can I help you prove something that is false?

Comment: " regarding your comment of induction, $3^n+9∗3^{n−1}$".  If I assume $a_{n} < 3^n$ (which it isn't).  And I assume $a_{n-1} < 3^{n-1}$ (which it isn't).  I would ga $a_n + 9a_{n-1} < 3^n + 9*3^{n-1}$.  But that is *not* less than $3^{n+1}$ so it will *not* work as an inductive step.

Comment: yes, but how did you derive $a_n + 9a_{n-1}$ to be less than $3^n +9 *3^{n-1}$?